# Creating 2 implementations of the same method name; one from @Override, and another for the derived

Tags: java, iterator, overriding

I know this question has been asked a million times but I'm not quite sure I have the solution I need. There could very well be a "NO" answer to this question but I am open to other solutions to this problem.

I am implementing my own Exception class which extends from another which also implements Iterable.

```
class TCBPackageException extends TCBRuntimeException implements Iterable<TCBRuntimeException> {

private List<TCBRuntimeException> exceptions = new LinkedList<>();

TCBPackageException(Throwable t) {
    super(t);
}

class TCBPackageIterator extends Iterator<TCBRuntimeException> {

    public boolean hasNext() {
        ...
    }
    public TCBRuntimeException next() {
        ...
    }
}

public void addException(TCBRuntimeException e) {
    exceptions.add(e);
}


//  Here's My ISSUE


// When getMessage() is Called on TCBPackageException I want the accumulation of all the messages stored.

@Override
public String getMessage() {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(super.getMessage());
    for (TCBException ex : exceptions) {
        buffer.append(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

// If I use an Iterator and end up getting this as the FIRST object, I just want the message of THIS exception.
public String getMessage() {
    return super.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement?

Comment: Conditional on what?

Comment: From the comment in your code, "If I use an Iterator and end up getting this as the FIRST object".

Comment: You should be getting a compiler error because you cannot have two methods with the same signature. The Override is not part of the signature.

Comment: Correct.  I cannot do this.  And @Radiodef, the comment is a little misleading, this may not be the FIRST iteration, it may just be an iterable object.

Comment: Is there a way to determine within the method which class called the method?

Comment: I think you should edit the question to clarify then, that what you need is to know how to test if `this` is in the list of exceptions and if so return something different. The question as it's written has the markings of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), that is, asking about your idea for a solution rather than the problem itself. You're likely to get much more useful answers if you edit with clarifications.

Comment: I'll try and rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists (there are some qualifications to this that will be discussed in the lesson titled "Interfaces and Inheritance").

Concidering this, you can't define two methods having absolute the same signature (annotations like @Override do not belong to signature). If you would define two methods `getMessage()` witout any difference, the compiler would not know which one you are trying to call by `o.getMessage()`.

You have to name them differently or define different set of parameters. Proposal:

```
@Override
public String getNestedMessages() {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(super.getMessage());

    for (TCBException ex : exceptions) {

        buffer.append(ex.getMessage());

    }

    return buffer.toString();

}
```

The second method `getMessage()` is absolutely obsolete then, since you would automatically call it from the super class if you do not override it.

Comment: Sure.  This is my problem.  I am expecting other users to be using this exception so I cannot enforce anything besides the standard `Exception` method calls.

Comment: but what behavior do you expect to have? do you want your users to call the same method and get different results depending on nothing? If you want your users to call only getMessage, then you have to make the decision yourself in the overriden getMessage method (like @user699848 already mentioned you could make an if-else block and decide there either to execute your own code or to call the super.getMessage

Comment: just think about to get ONE method generated by an external tool in the target class and you want to OVERWRITE the "auto-generated" method with your OWN implementation.